# Markdown converts formatting characters in raw URLs, rendering the displayed URL incorrect

Tags: bug, markdown, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering

Example: `https://example.com/repo/__tests__/asdf.js`

[https://example.com/repo/**tests**/asdf.js](https://example.com/repo/__tests__/asdf.js)

The underscores in the URL should be preserved, but are instead used to bold part of the URL. This can be a little confusing to someone who is reading a post and correcting a URL elsewhere, or copying only part of a URL, instead of right-clicking to "copy link location".

There are workarounds:

- Wrap raw URLs in `backticks`
- Notice the formatting and use the `edit` link to find the correct URL
- Copy the entire link src, instead of copying the rendered URL

Discovered on [Unit testing route matching with React Router 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35943786/unit-testing-route-matching-with-react-router-2#answer-35966985)

Comment: In that case, they could have just made the text "in our test for `matchRoutes`" a link without showing the bare URL. I find the cases where I need a bare URL are few and far between. But I agree it shouldn't format the URLs.

Comment: "Wrap raw URLs in `backticks`" no freaking no, just use the less,more than symbols https://example.com/repo/__tests__/asdf.js